# How to delete images uploaded to Cloudinary using CarrierWave? [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary and CarrierWave to handle my image uploads. [This is the guide](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_carrierwave#carrierwave_integration) that I'm following. I have a `Collection` model with a `cover` column of `type: string`:

**collection.rb**

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :cover, ImageUploader
end
```

And below is my **image_uploader.rb**:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  version :default do
    cloudinary_transformation quality: "auto", width:640, crop: "scale", fetch_format: "auto"
  end

end
```

I'm using **simple_form** for the upload form:

```
= simple_form_for @collection do |f|
  = f.input :cover, label: false, include_blank: true, input_html: { onChange: 'window.loadFile(event)' }
```

Now, the uploading works fine. For every image uploaded, the `cover` column of that particular `Collection` changes to the URL of the uploaded image. No issues there. BUT, I can't seem to find a way to delete an uploaded image. Sure, I can replace an uploaded image with another, but I can't ***remove*** it, so that the `cover` column becomes `nil` again. I've tried updating the attribute to `nil` or `''` from both the upload form and the rails console, but neither works. I've also tried `@collection.remove_cover!` as mentioned in the [CarrierWave guide](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), which didn't work either. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the delete method on the `file` attribute of your Carrierwave object, e.g.:

```
@collection.cover.file.delete
```

Assuming the `delete_remote` methods is set to true (default), it will remove the instance from your model, as well as from Cloudinary storage.

See: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/carrier_wave.rb#L172

Comment: When I try `@collection.cover.file` it does show the file, but when I type in `@collection.cover.file.delete`, it returns `=> {"result"=>"not found"}`. I tried `@collection.cover.file.exists?` too and that returns `=> false`. Why is this happening? Do I have Cloudinary set up wrong?

Comment: Sounds like it was already removed from your Cloudinary account. Did you notice otherwise? Looks like the operation succeeded and the File instance was removed along with the remote Resource. If it was there it would have been removed following this line of code.